# Discord countdown timer bot that will edit itself as timer goes down

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've created a Discord bot that can do a countdown timer. Now I want it to be able to send an embed message to the channel and as the timer counts down I want the bot to edit the original message to say something different without sending another message to the channel.
It currently will send a new message every time as it counts down.

Current Style:

`Game starts in 1 minute`

`Game starts in 30 seconds`

`0 - Game Starting!`

Wanted Style:
`Game starts in 1 minute`
<-- Then edit that message to say
`Game starts in 30 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

So, what you basically want to do is Editing the Message. That is possible using `<Message>.edit()` method of the message. So what you'll want to do is kinda like this. (You can check the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit))

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send("Game starts in 1 min");

// Then use msg.edit instead of message.channel.send for the new message

await msg.edit("Game starts in 30 seconds");
```

Remember that you need to use this in an async function, since we are using `await message.channel.send` and `await msg.edit`.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately that won't work with the current code

Comment: Why not exactly?